# SharePoint 2010 - Javascript to update list item value according to title

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Do you guys got any idea on updating the list item value according to criteria such as [title] by using javascript and also how to trigger javascript from sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your JS file then add it to your site. Then you have to create a SharePoint site page and then add a script editor webPart to it. Select your JS code from where ever you placed it in SharePoint. When the file comes up copy the URL from the browser (or whichever way you can get the URL that points to that file). Then go to the SharePoint page you created click on edit webPart and add the URL. You probably want to add a UI fro the to modify and target specific lists titles.

in the JS code you will need to get a reference to the SharePoint SP.js script by executing the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded function. Place this at the top of you JS file.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded( yourFunctionHere, 'sp.js' );
```

From there you'll need to get the current SharePoint context, the web that you are in, select the list that you want to target, and finally us the SharePoint executeQueryAsync function that is on the context object. This has to be done before you can manipulate and of the SharePoint.

```
function yourFunctionHere(yourSiteWebURL){
        var clientContext, itemCreatInfo, targetList, newListItem;

        // define a ClientContext for the specified SP site.
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(yourSiteWebURL);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync( function(){

            // Grab the SP.ListItemCreationInformation Constructor to add list items.
            itemCreatInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

            // Target the desired list.
            targetList =  oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('yor targeted list');

            // Assign the targeted list and item ListItemCreationInformation to a variable.
            newListItem = targetList.addItem(itemCreatInfo);

            // Create the list items [Header, Value] format.
            newListItem.set_item('Title', 'new list title value');

            // Update the list.
            newListItem.update();

        });

        clientContext.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message());
        }); 
    };
```

Comment: Andre, thanks for reply. If I want to update a column according to the criteria, example [Title], is that possible?

Comment: Are you talking about evaluating the value in the "Tilte" column and then doing something based on that value?